# Returning the correct item from the array

Tags: javascript, code.org

I am using code.org and I am trying to return the item from the array but receiving an error on line 34 that possibleFoods[selectedFood] is undefined. I cannot understand why, and is this what is stopping the food selections block from working? How should I correctly define selectedFood?

```js
setScreen("BaseScreen");
onEvent("selectionbutton", "click", function( ) {
    setScreen("food_decision_screen");
});
var selections = [true, true, true];
var possibleFoods = [
    {name:"Raw pasta prima vera", info:{recipe:"", prepTime:{total:20,cook:0,  prep:20}, image:""}},
    {name:"Zucchini chips",       info:{recipe:"", prepTime:{total:55,cook:30, prep:25}, image:""}}
];

var possibleFoods;
onEvent("preference_finished_button", "click", function( ) {
    selections = [
        getChecked("radio_buttonhot"),
        getChecked("radio_buttonvege"),
        getChecked("radio_button0-30") 
    ];

    if (selections[0] == false) {    
        if (selections[1] == false) {      
            if (selections[2] == true) {        
                selectedFood = 1;        
            }         
        }    
    }

    setText("t_textOutputFoodInfo", "total time: " + 
    possibleFoods[selectedFood].info.prepTime.total);
    setText("t_textOutput_foodSelectedName", "name: " + 
    possibleFoods[selectedFood].name);   
});
```

`selectedFood` is undefined. Unsure how to define.

Comment: Whats the output of `console.log(selections) ` before if conditions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean, but I think you want "true, true, true."
Still new to this, but thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

The selectedFood variable is not declared. Moreover, you are assigning it inside nested if conditions which might not be true always.

Try this:

Declare selectedFood outside with an initial value, right before the if statements.

```
var selectedFood = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few problems here:

1. selectedFood is not being declared- e.g it has no "const", "var" or "let" before it.
2. If you do not know about scopes and the difference between var, const and let- read a bit [here](https://codeburst.io/learn-let-var-and-const-in-easiest-way-with-guarantee-e6ecf551018a). Then you'll understand why its best to define `selectedFood` before the `if` blocks, and only fill up the value inside, like this:

   ```
   let selectedFood;    
   if (selections[0] == false) {    
      if (selections[1] == false) {  
         if (selections[2] == true) {   
            selectedFood = 1;    
         }    
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`selectedFood` is undefined simply because it's not declared, in addition this line is never reached in your case: `selectedFood = 1;`.
Depending on what you're trying to achieve, build your conditions using [Logical Operators](https://javascript.info/logical-operators).

replace this:

```
if (selections[0] == false) {

if (selections[1] == false) {


if (selections[2] == true) {

selectedFood = 1;

} 

}

}
```

With this:

```
let selectedFood = 0; // Set by default to 0
if (!selections[0] && !selections[1] && selections[2]) {
selectedFood = 1;
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: I might be able to give a more straight forward answer if you could link me to the challenge you're trying to solve.